# f_open returning FR_INVALID_NAME

Tags: csv

I'm working with a sd card and I need to create a new csv file every 5min.

So everytime my timer expires I'm creating a file called "newfile0.csv", newfile1.csv", and so on and so forth. It works as expected until I get to "newfile10.csv". By this moment, I start to get a `FR_INVALID_NAME` return value of the `f_open` function.

I've already tried different approaches to create the string which contains the file name. I also have checked the string contents before I call `f_open` and the result is okay.

I'll put some of my code here.

```
char *file_name = (char*)calloc(17,sizeof(char));
if (file_name != NULL )
    printf("error");

char *number = (char*)calloc(10,sizeof(char));
if (number != NULL )
    printf("error");

if (count_files < MAX_NO_FILES){
    count_files++;

    strcat(file_name, "lewfile");
    itoa(file_name, number);
    strcat(file_name, number);
    strcat(file_name, ".csv");
    printf("CONCATENATED STRING: %s", file_name);

    fileSystemResult = f_open(&fileObject[count_files], file_name,      FA_CREATE_ALWAYS | FA_WRITE);
    if (fileSystemResult != FR_OK)
        printf("error creating the file: %d \n\r",fileSystemResult );
```

Any hints what I may have missed?

Comment: What's the filesystem? The fact the it breaks when you try to create a filename with more than 8 characters in the name is reminiscent of things that I haven't seen in a long time.

Comment: I'm using the FAT32 filesystem

Answer (score 5):

Your filesystem probably only supports the 8.3 format file name (SFN). It breaks when you try using 9 characters for the filename.

Try creating "newf0.csv", newf1.csv", and so on. See whether it breaks when you reach "newf10.csv".

Comment: Thanks for your help but I think that's not the problem because I've manually created a file called "newfile100.csv" and it worked fine..

Comment: Ups, it seems you were right , I've tested your sugestion and it's perfect now. Thank you very much!